# Obtain cookies as dictionary from a QWebEngineProfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, pyqt5, qtwebengine

Title explains it all really. Would like to know how to get the cookies of a QWebEngineProfile as a dictionary of their names and values or in a json format. I am using PyQt5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`QWebEngineCookieStore` is a class that manages cookies and we can access this object through the `cookieStore()` method, in order to obtain cookies it can be done asynchronously through the `cookieAdded` signal, in the following part we show an example:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        profile = QWebEngineProfile("storage", self.webview)
        cookie_store = profile.cookieStore()
        cookie_store.cookieAdded.connect(self.onCookieAdded)
        self.cookies = []
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, self.webview)
        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.load(
            QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150321/obtain-cookies-as-dictionary-from-a-qwebengineprofile"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)

    def onCookieAdded(self, cookie):
        for c in self.cookies:
            if c.hasSameIdentifier(cookie):
                return
        self.cookies.append(QNetworkCookie(cookie))
        self.toJson()

    def toJson(self):
        cookies_list_info = []
        for c in self.cookies:
            data = {"name": bytearray(c.name()).decode(), "domain": c.domain(), "value": bytearray(c.value()).decode(),
                    "path": c.path(), "expirationDate": c.expirationDate().toString(Qt.ISODate), "secure": c.isSecure(),
                    "httponly": c.isHttpOnly()}
            cookies_list_info.append(data)
        print("Cookie as list of dictionary:")
        print(cookies_list_info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Next time - include the imports, dude ;)

Comment: The imports

`from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie`

Answer (score 0):

Updated for PyQT6:

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl, QSize, QDateTime, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt6.QtGui import QKeySequence, QAction
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QToolBar
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage
from PyQt6.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie
import json

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumWidth(1024)
        self.setMinimumHeight(800)

        # Create a web view
        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        profile = QWebEngineProfile("storage", self.webview)
        cookie_store = profile.cookieStore()
        cookie_store.cookieAdded.connect(self.onCookieAdded)
        self.cookies = []
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, self.webview)
        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150321/obtain-cookies-as-dictionary-from-a-qwebengineprofile"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)

        # Create a toolbar
        toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        # Add a back action to the toolbar
        back_action = QAction("Back", self)
        back_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Back"))
        back_action.triggered.connect(self.webview.back)
        toolbar.addAction(back_action)

        # Add a forward action to the toolbar
        forward_action = QAction("Forward", self)
        forward_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Forward"))
        forward_action.triggered.connect(self.webview.forward)
        toolbar.addAction(forward_action)

        # Add a reload action to the toolbar
        reload_action = QAction("Reload", self)
        reload_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Refresh"))
        reload_action.triggered.connect(self.webview.reload)
        toolbar.addAction(reload_action)

        # Add a search bar to the toolbar
        self.search_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.search_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.load_url)
        toolbar.addWidget(self.search_bar)

    def onCookieAdded(self, cookie):
        for cookie in self.cookies:
            if cookie.hasSameIdentifier(cookie):
                return
        self.cookies.append(QNetworkCookie(cookie))
        self.toJson()

    def toJson(self):
        cookies_list_info = []
        for c in self.cookies:
            data = {
                "name": bytearray(c.name()).decode(),
                "domain": c.domain(),
                "value": bytearray(c.value()).decode(),
                "path": c.path(),
                "expirationDate": c.expirationDate().toString(),
                "secure": c.isSecure(),
                "httponly": c.isHttpOnly()
            }
            cookies_list_info.append(data)
        print("Cookie as list of dictionary:")
        print(cookies_list_info)

    def load_url(self):
        url = self.search_bar.text()
        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = "https://" + url
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Only with this line:

```
"expirationDate": c.expirationDate().toString(),
```

I'm not sure, if that is correct - it works but attempts like:

```
"expirationDate": c.expirationDate().toString(QDateTime),
```

are ending up with a runtime error.

The provided code was very helpful for me, the widget works now proper with saving the credentials over a session / restart of the widget.